# Intel Parallel Studio 2018 Mac Installation Issues

Tags: intel-mkl

I am trying to install Intel Parallel studio 2018 on a Mac (Sierra OS). I should set the environmental variables. I tried

```
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.104/mac/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh  intel64
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.104/mac/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
```

However when I try to run icc or icpc from terminal I get the error

```
-bash: icc: command not found
```

How to set properly the MKL library? What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Check that wherever `icc` is has shown up in your `PATH`.

Comment: I solved the problem, just I had installed the wrong library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set Intel MKL properly one has to add to .bash_profile

```
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.104/mac/bin/compilervars.sh intel64
source /opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.104/mac/mkl/bin/mklvars.sh intel64

export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries/mac/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.0.104/mac/compiler/:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"
```